# How do I develop software for Windows phone 7 with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7

I have Visual Studio 2008. Do I develop software for Windows phone 7 with Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. You download the [Windows Phone 7 SDK](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7-series/) instead. That will work independently of VS2010, or if you have VS2010 installed as well, it will become another set of project types.

Comment: But not yet, the current download only works with VS2010 RC, not with the final release. Read carefully.

Comment: @Henk: Yes, that's true - and indeed why I'm holding off installing the RTM for the moment. Hopefully it won't be long before they come out with a compatible sdk though.

Comment: Next month (May) is when Microsoft are making some more announcements about Windows Phone 7 and also rumoured to be releasing an update to the tools for the Release version of VS2010, which they have already implied this month that they are doing this.