# is there a way to get windows phone 7 phone emulator for visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-phone-7, emulation

Does anyone know of a way i integrate this emulator with visual studio 2008 so that i can test my mobile applicables?

http://www.redmondpie.com/standalone-windows-phone-7-series-emulator-9140536/

Comment: Are you looking for a Windows Phone 7 emulator? Or regular Windows 7?

Comment: my bad, win 7  phone emulator

Comment: I've edited the title and tags on the assumption that you're talking about Windows *Phone* 7, given your remark about testing mobile applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i develop software for Windows phone 7 with Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669718/how-do-i-develop-software-for-windows-phone-7-with-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 8):

The Windows Phone 7 development tools only work with Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend for Windows Phone, however, all of these tools are free. If you download and install the [Windows Phone Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en), the installation includes:

- Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone
- Windows Phone Emulator Resources
- Silverlight 4 Tools For Visual Studio
- XNA Game Studio 4.0
- Microsoft Expression Blend for Windows Phone

All of the above are free and enable you to develop and test your WP7 applications on the emulator and on a developer unlocked device. In order to test your application on an actual device you will need to register for a developer account on the [AppHub](http://create.msdn.com).

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone 7 tools run under Visual Studio 2010 only. During CTP for WP7, the tools were released under VS2010 beta.

You can have a VS2008 and VS2010 install side by side. The WP7 tools ship with VS2010 express, so you get this for free. If you did this along side VS2008, you would have access to VS2008, VS2010 and the emulator on one PC, however VS2008 and the WP7 SDK would not be integrated as it is in VS2010.

There is not currently a way to install WP7 tools without getting 2010. Though it has been requested many times by people with existing VS2010 paid installs.

Comment: @Kevlark That link merely describes how to run the emulator without also running the IDE. A VS2010 install is still required: *"If you have installed the development tools (including Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows phone)"*

Comment: @Kevlark Insofar as I copied the italicized text in my comment from the second sentence of the linked article using the generally-reliable Windows clipboard... Yes, it does, in fact, say that. :P

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce the windows Phone 7 dev tools contain Visual Studio 2010 Express and to have the emulator running you should install those tools, so it would not work with VS 2008.

Comment: My main question is how to do it without downloading 2010